# Writing a multi-thread code to read a file in C

Tags: c, pthreads

I am self studying threads in c and find it very hard to understand. I found this question from a book. The task is to create three separate threads to read separate lines from text a file. The file has 3 numbers 3 letters and 3 symbols written down.

```
1
2
3
A
B
C
#
@
!
```

And it asks to create three threads for reading numbers letters and symbols and print them using pthreads.

Sample output:

Number: 1   Letter:A   Symbol:#

If someone could help me or provide a simple sample/skeleton code that could developed into this that would mean alot.

Thank you for your time and attention. I couldn't find anything similar.

Comment: No, we will not provide from-scratch sample code.  We are not a coding service.  If you have a specific question about code you've written for this exercise then that would be more likely to be answered.

Comment: check out the pread function.

Comment: You have to start with trying to understand the task first. your description tells me that you do not. Think of threads a parallel tasks, e.g. 3 people doing it independently.

Comment: thank you PSkocik and Serge for answering. Tbh what I understand is, three threads must be created for reading each set of lines. And one must wait until the other is finished. And the thread should be joined in the end. I was expecting a skeleton code for this program. I wasn't asking for an entire code. Thanks for any help and correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

From you question is not clear how the threads should behave. One of the issues is that when you read lines from a file, you have no idea what the line contains till you read it. So, spawning separate threads for reading different types of lines is not possible.

What can be done instead is to have a main process to read a line from a file and then spawn a thread which can do something with the read line.

So, your skeleton program might look like this:

```
 loop (read-line)
     if line is a number --> spawn the thread for numbers
     else if line is a char --> spawn the char thread
     else if line is a punctuation --> spawn the punctuation thread
 end loop
 join all threads.
```

of course this would spawn as many threads as there are lines in the file. You need to keep their IDs in order to join them one by one at the end. In this case you can probably can get away with no synchronization.

The other way around is to create 3 threads upfront and feed them with the correct data. this is more complicated, but will save resources:

```
  start 3 threads for different types
  loop (read-line)
     if line is a number --> wake up the thread for numbers
     else if line is a char --> wake up the char thread
     else if line is a punctuation --> wake up the punctuation thread
   end loop
   signal all threads to finish
   join 3 threads
```

you would need to use conditional variables for this (or other signalling scheme).

Comment: I tried you solution and, This is what I cam up with, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57910180/modifying-a-pthread-programme